# Robot Framework ride.py Tool, How to Achieve textbox Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, robotframework, python-3.6

I'm learning selenium automation testing, using Robot Framework with **ride** tool.

I'm facing difficulty to achieve textbox autocomplete, I'm not select a value from autocomplete list.
please help to overcome this problem,

For reference, I have attached photo

[ride tool, test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykwho.png)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot we can see that the `Input Text` is correctly identified. So, if you press Ctrl-SPACE there should be a list of SeleniumLibrary keywords. On the cell with the value,  pressing Ctrl-SPACE should show a list of variables starting with "r", for example, ${rakesh} if it exists.

Comment: Sorry that is not my question, actually i have one simple application in that one textbox is there with autocomplete feature.

if i pass value ex. 'rakesh' to textbox, it will display all respective values starts with rakesh in autocomplete  in which i want to select one value

Comment: anyway i found solution, Thanks @helio

Comment: So your question is not well formulated. Please, next time, be more precise when asking. Do not mention the Editor you are using (RIDE) if it is not a problem with it.